# SQL group and ordering by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, subquery

Well, I have a SQL table that is as below:

```
Name title dept salary
Abc aaaa qazwsx 15
Abc aaaa hehene 73
Abc aaaa geneh 55
Abc bbbb thghbh 33
Abc bbbb hehehe 433
Abc bbbb eyehhe 54
```

Statement to create data -

```
CREATE TABLE #StackOverflow
(Name VARCHAR(5)
,Title VARCHAR(5)
, Dept VARCHAR(10)
, Salary INT);

INSERT INTO #StackOverflow
(Name, Title, Dept, Salary)
SELECT 'Abc', 'aaaa', 'qazwsx', 15  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc', 'aaaa', 'hehene', 73  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc', 'aaaa', 'geneh', 55   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc', 'bbbb', 'thghbh', 33  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc', 'bbbb', 'hehehe', 433 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc', 'bbbb', 'eyehhe', 54
```

I need to write a query which will give me the top 2 depts whose name are `abc` and title is `aaaa` , whose name is `abc` and title is `bbbb`. This should be ordered by salary!

How do I implement it using SQL sub queries?

Comment: Please show some more effort... What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH X AS 
 (
  SELECT * 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Title
                           ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn 
  FROM TableName 
 )
SELECT * 
FROM x 
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Comment: The question asks for top 2 for each  name, title combination I believe.

Comment: cheers @MartinSmith I misread the question :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 2 dept
   FROM table 
   WHERE name='abc' AND title='aaaa'
   ORDER BY salary DESC;
```